# How to create an object out of two objects from javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am dealing with Javascript Application, where I have one object and one Array object and i would like to create a new object out of these two.

Objects i Have:

```
let test1 = { p1: 50, p2: 0, p3: 1 };
let test2 = [ { code: 'p1', search_key: 'search_p1' }
            , { code: 'p2', search_key: 'search_p2' }
            , { code: 'p3', search_key: 'search_p3' }
            ];
```

Final result would be:

```
let test3 = {search_p1: 50, search_p2: 0, search_p3: 1};
```

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: What part do you need help with?  Where are you stuck? What did you try?

Answer (score 2):

A simple iteration through test2, then assignment in a new object test3:

```
let test1 = {p1: 50, p2: 0, p3: 1};
let test2 = [ {code: 'p1', search_key: 'search_p1'}, {code: 'p2', search_key: 'search_p2'}, {code: 'p3', search_key: 'search_p3'} ];
const test3 = {};

test2.forEach((element) => {
    test3[element.search_key] = test1[element.code];
});
// { search_p1: 50, search_p2: 0, search_p3: 1 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.reduce` to create a new object out of the array.  (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Here I also use es6's dynamic object keys syntax as well as the `object spread operator` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to return a new object on each iteration, adding a new entry to the object where the key is the value of item.

`search_key` and the value is the value of test1[item.code]

```js
let test1 = { p1: 50, p2: 0, p3: 1 };
let test2 = [ { code: 'p1', search_key: 'search_p1' }
            , { code: 'p2', search_key: 'search_p2' }
            , { code: 'p3', search_key: 'search_p3' }
            ];

const test3 = test2.reduce((accum, item)=>({ ...accum, [item.search_key]: test1[item.code] }), {})

console.log( JSON.stringify(test3))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map the array and build an array of etries fro a new object.

```js
let test1 = { p1: 50, p2: 0, p3: 1 },
    test2 = [{ code: 'p1', search_key: 'search_p1' }, { code: 'p2', search_key: 'search_p2' }, { code: 'p3', search_key: 'search_p3' }],
    result = Object.fromEntries(test2.map(({ code, search_key }) => [search_key, test1[code] ]));

console.log(result);
```